# VM Packing in Cloud Computing

Tags: virtual-machines, cloud-computing

I was reading some paper on Cloud computing which mentions that if we do better VM Packing, then the cost of building the cloud is reduced. From what I understand, it means that somehow size of VMs can be reduced and they are more properly packed and that would help in increasing the number of VMs we can support and in turn, decrease the cost. Firstly, I am not sure, if I am correct in understand about? Also, can someone please explain what VM packing means?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

Comment: Essentially, if your VM hosts have 8 GB of RAM, and your instances have 1, 3, 5, and 7, you'd want to put the 3s and 5s together, the 1s and 7s together, etc. to waste minimal capacity on the underlying machines.

Comment: @ceejayoz basically like in operating systems, to reduce the fragmentation. right?

Comment: Essentially. If you put the 5 and the 1 on one server, you'd need three VM hosts total, which would be a waste of a server's worth of capacity. The numbers are rarely that neat, but that's the general idea. IMO, it's only something worth worrying about if you have a pretty big number of VM hosts.